# Polling a stopping or starting EC2 instance with Boto

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto

I'm using AWS, Python, and the [Boto library](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/ec2.html).

I'd like to invoke `.start()` or `.stop()` on a Boto EC2 instance, then "poll" it until it has completed either.

```
import boto.ec2

credentials = {
  'aws_access_key_id': 'yadayada',
  'aws_secret_access_key': 'rigamarole',
  }

def toggle_instance_state():
    conn = boto.ec2.connect_to_region("us-east-1", **credentials)
    reservations = conn.get_all_reservations()
    instance = reservations[0].instances[0]
    state = instance.state
    if state == 'stopped':
        instance.start()
    elif state == 'running':
        instance.stop()
    state = instance.state
    while state not in ('running', 'stopped'):
        sleep(5)
        state = instance.state
        print " state:", state
```

However, in the final `while` loop, the state seems to get "stuck" at either "pending" or "stopping".  Emphasis on "seems", as from my AWS console, I can see the instance does in fact make it to "started" or "stopped".

The only way I could fix this was to recall `.get_all_reservations()` in the `while` loop, like this:

```
    while state not in ('running', 'stopped'):
        sleep(5)
        # added this line:
        instance = conn.get_all_reservations()[0].instances[0]
        state = instance.state
        print " state:", state
```

Is there a method to call so the `instance` will report the ACTUAL state?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The instance state does not get updated automatically.  You have to call the `update` method to tell the object to make another round-trip call to the EC2 service and get the latest state of the object.  Something like this should work:

```
while instance.state not in ('running', 'stopped'):
    sleep(5)
    instance.update()
```

To achieve the same effect in boto3, something like this should work.

```
import boto3
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
instance = ec2.Instance('i-1234567890123456')
while instance.state['Name'] not in ('running', 'stopped'):
    sleep(5)
    instance.load()
```

Comment: Perfect -- that worked just right.  Not for nothing, but I wanted to state: I DID read the docs, and I just double checked... this method is NOT in the docs as of this writing!  Thanks again.

Comment: @garnaat please edit your answer and add instructions for boto3, in boto3 instead of `update()` you need to use `load()` - for future users to see

Answer (score 5):

The wait_until_running function in Python Boto3 seem to be what I would use.

http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Instance.wait_until_running

Comment: can you write some code so that people like me who come at this link may benefit as how to use instance.wait_until_running in their code

Answer (score 3):

This work for me too. On docs we have this:

`update(validate=False, dry_run=False)`
- Update the instance’s state information by making a call to fetch the current instance attributes from the service.

Parameters: `validate (bool)` 
– By default, if EC2 returns no data about the instance the update method returns quietly. If the validate parameter is `True`, however, it will raise a `ValueError` exception if no data is returned from EC2.